# How could I give users different access privilege in the same kerberos realm?

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos

I have a kerberos realm, for example EXAMPLE.COM and Apache Hive and Spark are kerberos service I have been configured successfully.

My question is that I want user A could access Hive and Spark both, and user B could only access Apache Hive.
Both A and B authenticate kerberos from the same machine.

How could I give A and B different access privileges to the services in the same kerberos realm?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Kerberos is used for *authentication*; your problem is to manage *authorization* -- that's different. And that's usually solved by defining ACLs *(access control lists)* and Groups, Roles, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the point.